# Does Global Access to Imported Variables in Functions Violate the Black-Box Paradigm?

Tags: python, oop, testing, design-patterns, global-variables

In Python, is it always advisable to access `import`-ed variables without going through the parameters of a function?  Doesn't this violate the black-box paradigm?

For instance: given the statement `from collections import deque`, I wouldn't expect that one would instantiate a `deque` object to be passed as a parameter along with every function.  Instead, I would expect that a `deque` would be instantiated as needed.

Suppose, though, that the imported object didn't belong to the canonical libraries in Python.  Would it be preferred to access such an object through the parameters of a function, or through the global scope?

Edit:
To help illustrate what I mean, take for instance the code below:

```
from collections import deque

def my_func():
    # this seems to be OK
    nodes = deque()
```

On the other hand, suppose that we had some other kind of object.  Would this be encouraged in Python?

```
from my_module import SomeClass

def my_func():
    # SomeClass accessed through global scope
    instance_of_some_class = SomeClass()
```

Doesn't the above violate black-box coding?  Alternatively:

```
from my_module import SomeClass

def my_func(some_class):
    # SomeClass accessed through local scope
    some_class.do_a_thing()

def main():
    # I suppose SomeClass() is being accessed globally here...but this is the crux of my question nonetheless.
    instance_of_some_class = SomeClass()
    my_func(instance_of_some_class)
```

I realize that as a matter of design, this may be open to opinion; mainly, I was curious if there is a prescribed recommendation in Python.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking, what do you mean "access such an object through the parameters of a function"?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example (in code) of what you're describing? `deque` is not a variable so the first paragraph doesn't make sense.

Comment: Rule of thumb: global state is fine if it isn't being mutated. e.g. just *referencing* some global variable, suppose a function, `from mylib import foo`, then using `foo()` inside your code is fine. BUt suppose you have someth9ing like, `from mylib import foo; foo.bar = baz` that's bad, but that is an issue of fundamental design

Comment: @Woodford well, yes, deque is a variable available in `collections`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga edited with a couple of examples to illustrate...hopefully that helps make it clearer

Comment: @Woodford added an example to help illustrate.  isn't `deque` an object imported from `collections`?  That's what I meant in the original writing, though I acknowledge I may have used incorrect or non-Pythonic term.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with black-blox programming, but in the latter example, you have inversion of control ("dependency injection") and in the former you don't. Whether this is a good or a bad thing has to be considered on a case-by-case basis

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that makes sense and I agree.  I suppose the answer is "it depends".

Comment: @Daniel I suppose you're not wrong since a variable is a named reference to an object. Here, `from ... import deque` creates a named reference to the `collections.deque` class (which is also an object).

Comment: @Woodford right...everything an object in Python :) thanks for clarifying though!

Comment: @Daniel so the classic consideration is testing your `my_func`. Let's say `MyClass` uses some resource, e.g. aws S3, but you don't want your test to actually download anything, you could use a `MyTestClass` and instantiate it and pass it to your function for the test. The alternative in your former case is to use mocking (pretty much, the lack of dependency injection is the reason mocking exists).